# how to fix wordpress [audio] player does not have an option to download audio

Tags: wordpress, html, html-table, audio-player

The problem I am experiencing has something to do with wordpress

```
[audio src="file_local/file.mp3"]
```

on chrome, it has a play option as well as an option to download,

but on firefox and safari, it just plays.

How do I fix it?

**Firefox:**

[image: firefox]

**Chrome:**

[image: chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers have different behaviours, as it is up to the manufacturer if they wan't to build in a download button or not. As a workaround you can use the [download `<a>` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) to create a download link:

```
<a href="file_local/file.mp3" download>Download this MP3 file</a>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1j8en21n/)